# Typescript compiler in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, tsc

I would like to know, if is there some option, how to exclude node_modules packages from TSC command.

I'm using Typescript v3.5.3. My tsconfig.json is

```jon
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "build",
    "config",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

And an angular script like this

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-home",
  styleUrls: ["./home.component.less"],
  templateUrl: "./home.component.html"
})
export class HomeComponent {
  title = "angular home";
  
  constructor(){
    this.log(123);
    this.log('hello world');
  }

  log(someArg) {
    console.log(someArg);
  }
}
```

Now i'm expecting error if i will run TSC, because function log is with implicit any type. In this case is everything ok! But if i will use this code

```js
import { Node } from "@alfresco/js-api";
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-home",
  styleUrls: ["./home.component.less"],
  templateUrl: "./home.component.html"
})
export class HomeComponent {
  title = "angular home";
  selectedNode: Node;
  
  constructor(){
    this.log(123);
    this.log('hello world');
  }

  log(someArg) {
    console.log(someArg);
  }

}
```

I will get errors from package from node_modules like

> node_modules/@alfresco/js-api/src/authentication/processAuth.ts:181:9 - error TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
>
> 181         this.authentications.basicAuth.username = null;
>               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I know why, beacuse "noImplicitAny" is set to true, but what i want is, to ignore node_modules packages! Therefore in Angular exclude option from tsconfig mean nothing. I think, that with build is package @alfresco/js-api included to script and checked as one.

Interesting thing is, if i will use similar code in React.js, everything is as i excpect. Is there some option or something, when i use command "TSC" with "noImplicitAny" = true and node_modules packages will be ignored? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmm I had a similar problem yesterday. So adding `node_modules/@alfresco` to `exclude` array in `compilerOptions` won't work?

Comment: No, doesn't work, even if i add exactly name of the script "processAuth.ts" doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files which are referenced using ***import*** will have to be compiled by ***tsc*** command. Exclusion is for convenience while running ***tsc*** command to exclude the files which are not imported (or used) in the files which are to be compiled.

By default, ***tsc*** command ignores ***node_modules***, thats why no errors when ***@alfresco/js-api*** is not imported and when it is included TSC will resolve them and imply the ***compilerOptions*** on these files as well.

Refer [tsconfig.json document](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

> Any files that are referenced by files included via the "files" or "include" properties are also included. Similarly, if a file B.ts is referenced by another file A.ts, then B.ts cannot be excluded unless the referencing file A.ts is also specified in the "exclude" list.

So it all depends on the error and the modules that are imported and not on the ***typescript*** compiler.

Please read this issue thread for more details, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7432

So for resolving this issue either use other modules or turn off the compiler options for Implicits.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know, how to check only mine code before build? I would like to have all mentioned tsconfig options, but imported packages means nothing for me (i don't want to check them). Thank you!

Comment: only one suggestion might work is waiting for eslint to be part of angular. there are few articles saying to migrate tslint to eslint, but i dont know if they work well or not.